# Need today's date to auto fill in a cell when data is entered into another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to have cells C5-C39 auto fill today's date whenever data is entered into cells B5-B39.

I have tried to get it to work using `=TODAY()` but don't how to structure the formula.

Comment: well, you can't just use `=TODAY()` since that keep recalculating ... I believe you'd need to do this with VBA. Setup a "macro" or function, then you just need to trigger it when you enter in the other cells (which I have no idea how to do - sorry :( )

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a VBA solution to me.

Comment: So =TODAY() would literally change every day then wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the simplest way to do this would be with a user-defined function. That function will update when any cell it references change, so you won't have to tie it into any events.

A function for your problem would be:

```
Function Updating_Date(dependent_cell as Range) As Date
  Updating_Date = Date
End Function
```

After having put that code into a module in your workbook, you can simply input `=Updating_Date(B5)` into `C5` and then copy it down. That should make the date in C5 update whenever the values in column C changes.

In order to make the date only appear if the cell in column B isn't blank, you could apply an if-formula in the cell in column C, as I touched on in [the other question you asked](https://superuser.com/questions/892962/i-need-a-cell-to-automatically-fill-when-data-is-entered-into-a-neighboring-cell). Simply enter the same conditional as I showed there (i.e. `ISBLANK(B5)`) and have the return-value be an empty string (`""`) if the condition is true, and the UDF (`Updating_Date(B5)`) if the condition is false.

Comment: So I have pasted this into the Sheet from the drop down on the left for my current workbook then entered the formula into cell C5 and now it just says, #NAME?

Comment: Again, it works fine for me - your VBA editor window should look something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/PaNMZoY.png), and the worksheet something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/DH4JAlb.png). Note that the cells aren't the exact same as in your question, but changing the address within the parantheses should be fairly trivial :)

Comment: So I wasn't putting the code into a module a first. I can get a date to show up but it appears even when nothing is in column b, and if you remove something from column b the date stays.

Comment: You could add a conditional inside the function, to check if the cell is empty @kyle

Comment: Could I modify this somehow and add it to what you provided me. (I'm trying to put this code on separate line but can't figure out how to skip lines).. 


`If CellsAreEmpty(Range("A1"), Range("B7"), Range("C9")) Then
        Debug.Print "Do stuff`

Comment: @KyleHinkebein I updated the answer to show how you could do it. Since the UDF returns a date, I think it would be a bit tricky to have it return an empty string, though you could of course have it return some kind of error if the cells you want filled aren't. I think you'll have a hard time getting the results the way you want them this way though. In regards to the code snippet you posted I can't really see how it is related to the question at hand. Is it something you have copied from somewhere else? If so, a link and more comprehensive description would be nice.

Comment: I had actually re-posted just a few minutes ago and someone beat you to the resolution, lol.. I appreciate it @eirikdaude.. Thanks for the line, you totally got it working for me..

Comment: It actually does return blanks now just like I wanted, thanks for getting me there..

Comment: Hey @eirikdaude, I've used code you provided me with for two consecutive days now and the Date changes to the current date instead of remaining on the date it was entered. Is there anyway to have it keep the date of input and not reflect todays current date?

Comment: I've checked the formula in my excel version now, and the date doesn't update, unless the value in the dependent cell changes, so I am not sure what is the problem in your workbook. @KyleHinkebein

Comment: Right on, I set up another one with different dates on it, maybe I somehow tweaked something without knowing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The following puts today's date in cell "B" whenever there is a change in cell "A":

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Auto Date
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("A:A").Column Then
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value = Int(Now)
        Else
            Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

This code needs to be placed in the VBA module for the worksheet where you want this behavior to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA. I needed my C column to fill in with today's date based on the B column have a value entered. This formula works to get it inserted correctly.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2)," ",NOW())
```

I placed this in the C2 cell since that is where I was starting for my C column. You can place this in whichever column's cell you're starting in. Then just make sure that my B2 reference is replaced with the column and cell your value is being entered into. For example, if your kick-off cell is F3, you should change the formula to say

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F3), " ",NOW()).
```

And if your corresponding date cell is K3, place formula there. (You can drag the formula to the rest of the column's cells once it's in the first one.)

This formula keeps the date cells empty until the "kick-off" cell has a value entered. Once that value is entered, the date is added. If the value is deleted, Excel will automatically remove the date. So it's not perfect, but if you need something more sophisticated, you probably need an Excel expert or a program that's handling this for you.

Answer (score -2):

AFIK, you will need to do this via VBA. You can create a function that will watch for changes on your worksheet, filters out only changes on cells B5-B39 and updates the cells in C accordingly.

UPDATE:
You will probably know to get into VBA using alt-F11.

Double click on the Excel object called Sheet1 or whatever sheet you are interested in (in the tree list top-left) to get to the code for that sheet.

Select Worksheet and Change from the 2 dropdowns. So you get code that looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

The variable "Target" is now available which is a reference to the cell that changes.

Add some code between those lines:

```
debug.Print Target
```

and hit ctrl-G to show the immediate window

Make some changes in the worksheet and switch back to the code, you will see the data you entered appear in the Immediate window.

Now change the code to say `if Target.` and you will see a drop-down of possible properties that relate to the Target variable.

With a couple of changes, you can get this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 2 And (Target.Row > 4 And Target.Row < 40) Then
        Debug.Print Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Which now only prints changes in the range you are interested in.

If you want to know how to change a value in a cell, you can record a macro of you doing that manually and examine the code. Hopefully you have enough to go on now. Let me know if not.

Comment: Interesting, voted down with no comment almost as soon as I hit save. You can vote me down if you like but that is the answer.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment that the OP needs to look at VBA. An answer would have a potential solution to the OPs problem.

Comment: I am trying to start working with VBA as I have another project that requires it, but I have no idea how to go about that, I know what VBA is and how to open it, that's about it. Would you have a quick example of what I might type into the script to perform such a function?

Comment: Actually, whilst I haven't written the code, the answer is indeed there. It will work and I've done it before.

Comment: So would I need to use something similar to the answer above yours, in conjunction with what you've provided to get this to work properly? The one above is providing me with the date but it's showing even when Column B is blank. Your seems to be the first part of a code that's now watching column B. It almost seems like I would need to blend to two somehow, also forgive my ignorance, total beginner and trying to learn/ get it..

Comment: No problem Kyle. If you record a macro of you updating a cell, you will get the command you need. A hint: ```Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = Now()```

Comment: I appreciate it man, I'm trying like heck to figure this thing out but have pretty limited time at work. I think I'm going to re-post a newer more finished question to try and get it finished up.. I'm going to have to take some tutorials, for whatever reason it's blowin my mind right now.. lol